# Set default values for multiply elements javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the default values for DOM elements using javascript.
First, I need to check if the field value is empty. If it is, then change the value into 0.
If it's not, then do nothing.

**Text fields:**

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_1" value="" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_2" value="1" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_3" value="" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
```

The number of fields always changing.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
var feature_value = document.getElementsByName("feature_values_" + "/^\d+$/").value;
if(feature_value !== ""){
    change the default values
}
```

And, as I understand, must use some loop, but I don`t know how to implement this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no matching by a regular expression.

Best solution is to use a common className and loop over the collection.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("commonClass");
```

Other option is using querySelectorAll with a "starts with" match

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='feature_value_']");
```

and the loop

```
var i;
for (i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
   if (!elems[i].value.length) {   //you might want to trim this 
       elems[i].value = "0";
   }
}
```

References:

- [MDN getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)
- [MDN querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

---

Edit, add the runnable snippet:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='feature_value_']");
var i;
for (i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
   if (!elems[i].value.length) {   //you might want to trim this 
       elems[i].value = "0";
   }
}
```

```html
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_1" value="" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_2" value="1" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
<input class="field" type="text" name="feature_value_3" value="" size="50" style="width: 350px;">
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn`t change anything(
console.log writes length: 0

Comment: Ah, I copied your code above which had the name wrong. There is no "s" in the actual name.

Comment: It still shows the length 0(
I'm using
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='feature_value_']");

Comment: Code is running fine for me, just updated it with [the snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996132/set-defalut-values-for-multiply-elements-javascript/25996287#25996287) to show it running. You are either trying to access the elements before they are loaded on the page or the name is wrong.

Comment: Yes! You were right!! The script executed before page loading. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 3):

The idea is correct, but you're missing the actual loop. It could look like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < feature_value.length; i++)
    if (feature_value[i].value === "")
        feature_value[i].value = "0";
```

Comment: I recommend using '===' since ("" == 0) is true

Comment: Answer fails to mention the first issue that the getElementsByName is wrong. Only answers half the question.